# Is ec2 r7iz instance supports QAT endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu

Is QAT endpoint available on [Amazon EC2 r7iz (Sapphire Rapids)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/r7iz/) instances?

Some part of Intel Sapphire Rapids (SPR) includes QAT endpoints not all SPR. Which can be seen in Intel Product Specification
Advanced Technologies => [Intel® QuickAssist Technology (QAT)](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-quick-assist-technology-overview.html)

For example:

- QAT endpoint exists on [Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8480+ Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/231746/intel-xeon-platinum-8480-processor-105m-cache-2-00-ghz.html)
- QAT does NOT exist on [Intel Xeon Gold 6430 Processor 60M Cache 2.10 GHz Product Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/231737/intel-xeon-gold-6430-processor-60m-cache-2-10-ghz.html)

Comment: [Accelerating API Security with Intel’s Latest Innovations](https://nonamesecurity.com/blog/accelerating-api-security-with-intels-latest-innovations) mentions both `r7iz` and QAT.

Comment: I think you provided the same link for both chips -- you might want to update the "NOT" link.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I fix the chip URL for "Exist"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.The noname security blog describes 2types of servers. One is the cloud (r7iz) and second is the onpremise (Intel NetSec Accelerator Reference Design). In the onpremise, it describes QAT. But it is not described r7iz with QAT.